# Neo4j Insertion taking more time

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, embedded-database

We are having about 50,000 nodes and 80,00,000 (80 lakhs) edges.

We are trying to insert this data into neo4j (embedded graph database) using java. But it's taking lot of time (hours together).

We want to know whether we are going wrong in insertion anywhere. we are using automatic indexes for nodes. The complete implementation is given below.

Please let me know what is going wrong and changes to do with the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nodeGraph obj = new nodeGraph();
        obj.createDB();
        System.out.println("Graph Database Initialised");
        obj.parseNodesCsv();
        System.out.println("Creating relationships in process....");
        obj.parseEdgesCsv();
        obj.shutDown();

}

public void createDB() {

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( DB_PATH ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "id,name" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_keys_indexable, "rel" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_auto_indexing, "true" ).
        newGraphDatabase();             
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        // Get the Node AutoIndexer, set nodeProp1 and nodeProp2 as auto
        // indexed.
        AutoIndexer<Node> nodeAutoIndexer = graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer();
        nodeAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty( "id" );
        nodeAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty( "name" );

        // Get the Relationship AutoIndexer
        //AutoIndexer<Relationship> relAutoIndexer = graphDb.index().getRelationshipAutoIndexer();
        //relAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty( "relProp1" );

        // None of the AutoIndexers are enabled so far. Do that now
        nodeAutoIndexer.setEnabled( true );
        //relAutoIndexer.setEnabled( true );
}

public void parseNodesCsv(){

        try 
        {
            CSVReader reader= new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/sandy/Desktop/workspacesh/importToNeo4j/nodesNeo.csv"),'  ','"');
            String rows[]=null;
            while ((rows=reader.readNext())!=null) 
            {
                createNode(rows);
                System.out.println(rows[0]);

            }
            reader.close();
        } 


        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Error: cannot find datasource.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}

public void parseEdgesCsv(){

        try 
        {
            CSVReader reader= new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/sandy/Desktop/workspacesh/importToNeo4j/edgesNeo.csv"),',','"');
            String rows[]=null; 
            while ((rows=reader.readNext())!=null) 
            {
                createRelationshipsUsingIndexes(rows);

            }
            reader.close();
        }   


        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Error: cannot find datasource.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}


public void createNode(String[] rows){

         Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
         try 
            {   
                firstNode = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label( rows[2] ));
                firstNode.setProperty("id",rows[0] );
                firstNode.setProperty("name",rows[1] );
                System.out.println(firstNode.getProperty("id"));
                tx.success();
            } 
            finally
            {
                tx.finish();
            }

}

public void createRelationshipsUsingIndexes(String rows[]){

        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try
        {
            ReadableIndex<Node> autoNodeIndex = graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
            // node1 and node2 both had auto indexed properties, get them
            firstNode=autoNodeIndex.get( "id", rows[0] ).getSingle();
            secondNode=autoNodeIndex.get( "id", rows[1] ).getSingle();

            relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.CO_OCCURRED );
            relationship.setProperty( "frequency", rows[2] );
            relationship.setProperty( "generatability_score", rows[3] );
            tx.success();   

        }
        finally
        {
              tx.finish();
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the memory config (heap) you are using for your import? What OS are you running on (I assume some Linux) and what Neo4j version are you using?

I recommend upgrading to the latest stable version of Neo4j 2.0.3

There are a few problems with your import:

1. you're not passing mmio settings
2. don't use the legacy indexes
3. don't use one transaction per node, but one transaction per 50k nodes or 50k relationships
4. don't read from the index during insertion, use an in-memory structure for holding that information (e.g. a Map)
5. don't print output for each node, instead print an output for every tx commit (every 50k elements)
6. use a BufferedReader around your FileReader for better CSV read performance.

   **It would make more sense to use [my batch-importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20#binary-download) for fast initial imports**

Comment: We are using Ubuntu 12.04, Neo4j 2.0.1 community edition. We will change accordingly. What are mmio settings for neo4j server ?

Comment: Here are the relevant settings: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-io-examples.html

Comment: And unless CSVReader uses a buffered stream wrapper internally you should consider adding that as well. The data size indicated shouldn't take more than a few seconds to import if done right.

Comment: Hi Michael & Rickard, i followed your suggestions and now program is working reasonably well for insertion (less than 10 minutes). Now i need to get the sub-graph from the graph database. So which indexes i have to go for? (And i can't compromise performance !).